# Making (MPEG-4) movie from multi images (JPG) in MatLab

Tags: matlab

Please, I used below code to make a video from multi images (JPG). and it works fine. My problem that I have 10000 images and the code generate the movie with extension `avi`. This making the size of the movie very large. Are there anyways to save the movie with `mp4` extension?

```
cd('\\Desktop\Movies');
Files = dir('*.jpg');
NumFiles= size(Files,1);
Megamind_Images = uint8(zeros([600 1000 3 NumFiles*5]));
VideoObj = VideoWriter('Create_Video');
VideoObj.FrameRate = 5; 
VideoObj.Quality   = 80;  
count=1;
for i = 1 : NumFiles
I = imread(Files(i).name);
ResizeImg = imresize(I,[600 1000]);
 for j = 1 : 5
 Megamind_Images(:,:,:,count)=ResizeImg;
 count = count + 1;
end
end
open(VideoObj);
writeVideo(VideoObj, Megamind_Images);
close(VideoObj);
```

Comment: It autowriting as AVI is strange. I've never seen MATLAB do that before.  Did you try manually specifying the profile of the video? `VideoObj = VideoWriter('Create_Video.mp4', 'MPEG-4');`?

Comment: @rayryeng. Hello, Thank you so much. its working!

Comment: You're very welcome. I officially wrote an answer. If you don't mind accepting I'd be extremely grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try manually specifying the output profile of your video before writing frames to the object.

```
VideoObj = VideoWriter('Create_Video.mp4', 'MPEG-4');
```